# accessing an inner variable in a javascript object

Tags: javascript

Consider this errorful code:

```
x = {
  y : "why",
  z : function() {
    return y + " zed";
  }
}
```

The function z does not work: "ReferenceError: y is not defined".

Is there a way to access y from within the function z without fully specifying it as x.y?

I could of course rewrite this as

```
x = function() {
  var self = this;
  this.y = "why";
  this.z = function() {
    return self.y + " zed";
  };
  return this;
}();
```

... but gosh.

Answer (score 3):

Simply use `this` if you call the function with `x.z()`:

```
var x = {
    y : "why",
    z : function() {
        return this.y + " zed";
    }
};
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/hZxVu/

Comment: This is not infallible - consider var z = x.z; z(); //"undefined zed"

Comment: @meouw Indeed but otherwise I don't see any other options than OP's "rewritten" variant.

Comment: @meouw great point. I missed that too. I supposed you could complicate things with a closure to ensure y is always around: http://jsfiddle.net/YpX3B/

Comment: Contrary to @meouw, I think you shouldn't be doing var z=x.z; z(); because you should never assume functions can be called when detached from their  original owning objects. You should instead be doing varz=x;z.call(x); so I think this is not a valid objection.

Answer (score 0):

No, you will need to rewrite it as such. `y` is a property of that object, and you can't access it without the object - unlike accessing a variable (e.g. `self` in your rewrite) from a closure.

Of course, when you invoke the function as `x.z()`, the [`this` keyword](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) will point to the object too, so that you can write it as

```
return this.y + " zed";
```

as long as you *always* call the function in context of that object.

Answer (score 0):

@VisioN has the straight-forward answer. It might help to visualize why this is necessary if you rewrite your code as such:

```
var x = {};
x.y = "why";
x.z = function() {return this.y + " zed"; };
alert(x.z());
```

Here y and z are properties of an object, but there is no functional closure scoping. You need the "this" keyword to access a property of the parent object.

Alternatively,

```
var x = function () {
    var y = "why";     
    var z = function () { return y + " zed?"; };    
    return z();
};
alert(x());
```

This demonstrates functional scoping by accessing y without using this. Inside of `x`, `y` is known. Outside, it is not.

Answer (score 0):

Using the revealing module pattern:

```
    var x = (function () {
        y = "why";
        z = function() {
            return y + " zed";
        };
        return {
            "y": y,
            "z": z
        };
    })();

    //now you can call:
    x.y // "why"
    x.z() // "why zed"
```